# Des Decrypt read in C#

Tags: c#, encryption, des

```
static byte[] desdecrypt(Mode mode, byte[] IV, byte[] key, byte[] msg)
    {
        using (var des = new DESCryptoServiceProvider())
        {
            des.IV = IV;
            des.Key = key;
            des.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
            des.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;

            using (var mstream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                CryptoStream cs = null;
                if (mode == Mode.DECRYPT)
                {
                    cs = new CryptoStream(mstream, des.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Read);
                }
                if (cs == null)
                    return null;

                cs.Read(msg, 0, msg.Length); 
                return mstream.ToArray();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string a = textBox4.Text;
        string ab = textBox6.Text;
        byte[] IV = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(ab);
        string aa = textBox7.Text;
        byte[] key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(aa);
        byte[] decrypted = desdecrypt(Mode.DECRYPT, IV, key, Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(a));
        textBox5.Text = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(decrypted);
    }
```

cs.Read(msg, 0, msg.Length) error occurs in this line (bad data)
unhandled exception has occurred in my application
i dont know what any help please i have tried almost everything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have data in the underlying stream and want to decrypt it to an array, use `CryptoStreamMode.Read` and `Read`.

Since you have an empty stream that is collecting data, you should use `CryptoStreamMode.Write` and `Write`.

---

Standard caveats apply:

- DES is a terrible, broken algorithm
- Don't use ASCII (or Unicode) data as keys
- Don't assume that encrypted data can be represented as ASCII (or Unicode) data
- Never add cryptography into released software unless you can explain

  - What it does
  - Under what conditions it will be deemed out of date
  - How you will grow it up when it's out of date

    - And how it won't break all your users, or make them insecure, when you do so.